# MYSQL JOINS, Got Stuck

Tags: mysql, sql

good day! i'm in the middle of learning new thing in mysql, i need join 2 tables, table `aktifitas_materi` and table `hari`, i tried many join, but i think this is the closest one...

i'm using sql like this
`SELECT * FROM hari LEFT JOIN aktifitas_materi ON hari.id_hari = aktifitas_materi.id_hari WHERE id_materi = '1631246767791' AND id_user = '1631016713249' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM hari LEFT JOIN aktifitas_materi ON hari.id_hari = aktifitas_materi.id_hari`

this is looks good, `but` when i change `id_materi` or `id_user`, the data still the same, Even though the data should be null, idk why this happen, please helppp, where's the problem? :(

**THE PROBLEM**:
I think my data didn't get filter by `where`, because when i change `id_materi` or `id_user`, i got all the data...

**EXPECTED RESULT**

When i change `id_materi` or `id_user` to another number, i got data looks like this
[image: expected table]

---

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE `hari` (
  `id_hari` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hari` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `hari`
--

INSERT INTO `hari` (`id_hari`, `hari`, `timestamp`) VALUES
(1, 'Intro', '2021-09-10 03:42:52'),
(2, 'Hari 1', '2021-09-10 03:42:52'),
(3, 'Hari 2', '2021-09-10 03:42:52'),
(4, 'Hari 3', '2021-09-10 03:42:52'),
(5, 'Hari 4', '2021-09-10 03:42:52'),
(6, 'Hari 5', '2021-09-10 03:42:52'),
(7, 'Hari 6', '2021-09-10 03:42:52'),
(8, 'Hari 7', '2021-09-10 03:42:52');

CREATE TABLE `aktifitas_materi` (
  `id_aktifitas_materi` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `id_materi` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `id_hari` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_user` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `aktifitas_materi`
--

INSERT INTO `aktifitas_materi` (`id_aktifitas_materi`, `id_materi`, `id_hari`, `id_user`, `timestamp`) VALUES
('123213213', '23234234', 1, '123213213', '2021-09-10 11:01:13'),
('1631271674591', '1631246767791', 1, '1631016713249', '2021-09-10 11:01:13');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM `hari` LEFT JOIN aktifitas_materi ON hari.id_hari = aktifitas_materi.id_hari WHERE id_materi = '1631246767791' AND id_user = '1631016713249' UNION SELECT * FROM hari LEFT JOIN aktifitas_materi ON hari.id_hari = aktifitas_materi.id_hari;
```

| id_hari | hari | timestamp | id_aktifitas_materi | id_materi | id_user |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Intro | 2021-09-10 11:01:13 | 1631271674591 | 1631246767791 | 1631016713249 |
| 1 | Intro | 2021-09-10 11:01:13 | 123213213 | 23234234 | 123213213 |
|  | Hari 1 |  |  |  |  |
|  | Hari 2 |  |  |  |  |
|  | Hari 3 |  |  |  |  |
|  | Hari 4 |  |  |  |  |
|  | Hari 5 |  |  |  |  |
|  | Hari 6 |  |  |  |  |
|  | Hari 7 |  |  |  |  |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d8sTadRaz8b7xL83vEZmZR/0)

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to accomplish; your query looks (for lack of a better term) "silly" because you have the same query unioned to itself, just with different `where` conditions. Also qualify the column names so it is clear what table they are coming from.

Comment: I'm really sorry @GordonLinoff, just edited my post, please.. hope this new edit helps..

Comment: Please, drop the screenshots and provide a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com) with a sample of data.

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure (in text form!), sample input data, the expected result, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: I'm really sorry @NicoHaase, just edited my post, at the end of my post, i got image for expecting table output..

Comment: Please add all information **in text form**, not as screenshots. Also, share your attempts to resolve the problem.

Comment: There my fiddle @ΔO'deltazero', hope thats help..

Comment: I got my fiddle @NicoHaase, hopefully thats what you mean..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I GOT MY ANSWER!!!

changed my sql to
`select * from hari left join (select * from aktifitas_materi where id_materi = '' and id_user = '') tm on hari.id_hari = tm.id_hari`